# PL/SQL Procedure Variable instead of column name in insert statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to insert data into an Oracle database, but the column name where I want to insert isn't known in the first step, it depends on the user's choice.

For example:

```
colonne varchar(12) :=null;
...
case
  WHEN MOIS1 = 1 THEN 
    colonne :='col1';    
  WHEN MOIS1 = 2 THEN
    colonne :='col2';
  WHEN MOIS1 = 3 THEN
    colonne :='col3';
...    
insert into Mytable ( user_id, name, colonne, ...)
```

and it depend to the user `colonne` can be `col1`, `col2` or `col3`, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a column name like that, no. You could use dynamic SQL to build the insert statement and then bind the value, but since you have a limited choice you could also do this:

```
insert into mytable(user_id, name, col1, col2, col3)
values (v_user_id, v_name,
    case when mois1 = 1 then v_value else null end,
    case when mois1 = 2 then v_value else null end,
    case when mois1 = 3 then v_value else null end
);
```

You insert *something* into all three columns, but the `case` statements within the `values` clause determine whether you insert `null` or your actual value - you'll only put the real value into one of the three columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60364/4).

Comment: I will try it right now, but is it possible to use case inside the sql statement ?

Comment: @devosJava - yes; I've added an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60364/4) to demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry, but i have another constraint,its about insert .... select (...)  the logic still the same ?

Comment: @devosJava - yes it is; [another SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c77e/4) to demonstrate. Not sure why you didn't just try it though...